# OpenMP for loop with master region: "master region may not be closely nested inside of work-sharing or explicit task region"

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I have the following code, which I believe should display a progress bar approximating the progress of the entire process (since each parallel thread of the loop should be progressing at approximately the same rate)

```
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(long int x=0;x<elevations.size1();x++){
       #pragma omp master
       {
           progress_bar(x*omp_get_num_threads()); //Todo: Should I check to see if ftell fails here?
       }
           ........
    }
```

However, I get the following error:

```
warning: master region may not be closely nested inside of work-sharing or explicit task region [enabled by default]
```

Now, when I run the code I do get the desired result. But I don't like warnings. Why is this giving me a warning and is there a better way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is giving you the warning because
A master region may not be closely nested inside a worksharing, atomic, or explicit task region.

`#pragma omp master` is a master region as the name suggests and `#pragma omp parallel for` is a task sharing region.

They are closely nested because no function call or statement separates them.

In order to avoid the warning replace the `#pragma omp master` with something like

```
tid = omp_get_thread_num();
if(tid == 0)
{
   progress_bar(x*omp_get_num_threads());
}
```

as per the example [here](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/#ParallelRegion).

See [Guide into OpenMP: Easy multithreading programming for C++](http://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/openmp/) for more information and examples.

For further information see the [OpenMP Specification](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/spec30.pdf) or see [Intel's Documentation on Improper nesting of OpenMP constructs](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/composerxe/en-us/ptref/index.htm#pt_reference/references/sc_omp_global_nesting.htm).